# how to gather all dependencies resources from a gradle multiproject into a dist folder

Tags: java, scala, gradle, groovy, build

New to gradle here, I need to move all resources from the resources folder of my dependencies project (recursively) including current compiled project and concat file with a specific name i.e.

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':stam-common')
   compile project(':stam-db-common')
   compile project(':stam-reco') 
}
```

suppose I'm compiling project stam-this which depends on the modules above.
I need to move all files in each one of the four projects and it dependencies into one place and concatenate all application.conf files.

I can easily do it with some bash script but need it to be a gradle task.
any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what is in your `application.conf` you might need something more complicated but the simple answer is just ask each project for that file and combine them.

We can use Java's `streams` api and some Groovy's `File#text` to simplify the concat loop

```
def allAppConfs = rootProject.subprojects.stream().
        // using `Project#file(String)` the path will be
        // relative to the project's root
        map({ proj -> proj.file('src/main/resources/application.conf').text }).
        collect(Collectors.toList()).
        join('\n')
```